# Undefined symbol problems with SFML on mac m1

Tags: c++, xcode, sfml, apple-m1

I am new to SFML development, and I wanna run it on Mac M1. I follow the tutorial, I put all the packages in the directories where they should be, and yet when I run in XCode, build fails and it gives me
Showing Recent Issues
`Undefined symbol: sf::SoundStream::play()`
But like 35 of thos with different things after symbol:

What would be the solution to this?

Comment: You probably need to link to an additional library. `sfml-audio`

Comment: @drescherjm, how do I do this tho? also it's not only about sound, it's RenderStates, RenderTarget etc.

Comment: @EfimRubin did you manage to solve this? Having the same issue